# connect visual studio to 64 bit access

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ms-access, 32bit-64bit

I've had a problem that my c# (asp.net) code can't recognize the access database engine, even though I tried installing multiple versions of it.

Now I found out why - Since Visual Studio is 32 bit (no 64 bit version for some reason) it can only work with the 32 bit engine.

Unfortunately, 32 bit and 64 bit office products can't co-exist, and it prevents me from installing the 32 bit engine (I have 64 bit office).

Is there any way I can connect visual studio to the engine without uninstalling the whole office package?

EDIT: heres the code

```
public bool Connect(string connectionString)
{
    if (this.connection != null)
    {
        if (!this.connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
        {
            this.connection.Close();
        }
    }
    this.connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    this.connection.Open();
    return true;
}
```

with the connection string

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='|DataDirectory|\db.accdb'; Persist Security Info=False;
```

P.S: I know I should surround it with try-catch, I wan't to see the exceptions for debugging...

EDIT 2: I'm now trying to use the Jet provider instead of the ACE provider (and use the old access .mdb format), since it's not a part of office so I can have a version that VS supports, seems to work fine for now...

Comment: it shouldn't be Visual Studio that's the problem, it should be your compiled C# application. Is the application compiled for 32- or 64-bit architecture? The fact that Visual Studio itself is 32-bit shouldn't make any difference AFAIK. It can compile for other target architectures.

Comment: P.S. The reason VS is 32-bit only is very sensible - see this post https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/01/VS-64-bit

Comment: What specifically are you trying to connect to access? Some data tool within VS? Or your ASP.NET application written in C#? Don't confuse the IDE with the framework, they're different.

Comment: I try to connect the asp.net application. I do know that visual studio supports developing 64 bit stuff, and I don't get why It should be a problem with 64 bit, but it seems like it is the case (someone in another post here said that installing the 32 bit engine solved it). I guess that because I run the code through VS it runs in 32 bit? idk...

Comment: Your connect code is a disaster waiting to happen. Classes that implement [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) (like OleDbConnection) need to be handled correctly. They should either be `.Disposed` in a finally block or wrapping in a `using` statement. Your code will leak as it is.

Comment: It is disposed later in the code (I have a little wrapper class for common db functions, this is the 'connect' function, there is also 'close' function)

Comment: No, you have missed the point. If you are not handling your IDisposable correctly, you will have issues. Simply calling close at some later time does not guarantee that the connection will be closed. The only way to do so is to pick one of the two methods I have mentioned above. It will require rewriting your connect/disconnect logic, but it *must be done*.

Comment: What if an error happens between when you call your connect and close functions? Close isn't going to be reached. Therefore the connection will remain open. If that happens a few times you will exhaust the number of available connections (there is a limit) and your application will inexplicably stop working in a very hard to diagnose way. And once you do realize what happens, you will have to rewrite your code to solve the issue. It's much easier to correct the code up front before you use it everywhere. Learn why what I'm telling you is important and implement it!

Comment: I see, the thing is that I want to use the connection multiple times in different functions... What I thought of is having a giant `try` block for the whole `Page_Load` and closing the connection in the `finally` block of it.
(basically treating my wrapper class as a disposable object)

Comment: No, that's not a good pattern either. You should keep your database access in small blocks. Open the connection only right when you need it, and close it as soon as you done (closing happens automatically if you use a using statement), Are you familiar with the repository pattern?

Comment: On Stack Overflow make sure when you reply to someone who is not the asker/answerer of the thing you're commenting on that you use the `@username` syntax so they get notified about your reply. (unless you and that person are the only ones who have commented on that question/answer, in which case it'll assume who you're talking to and notify them)

Comment: @mason I am not familiar with the repository pattern, i'll look it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you could post the code that your using to connect to db would be great.
But here goes. Install this engine (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255) 32 bit. Since your visual studio will only 32 bit applications etc.

After I installing you should be able to use the following connection strings

```
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
```

Give that a go and let me know if that works. Also your code would help a lot.
If it did not work post a picture of the odbc sources. Open windows search and type odbc and then edit your post with a screenshot so i can what drivers you have installed.

Comment: I can't install the 32 bit engine because it confilcts with the 64 bit office i have. I guess if there is no solution i'll have to reinstall office :(

Comment: Oh i see. Have you tried odbc rather than oledb. Does that make a difference. Also

Comment: I didn't, now I'm trying using Jet provider instead of ACE, If it won't work i'll try odbc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where I have a 64 bit version of a driver and no 32 bit version.

I solved it by changing the platform target from Any CPU to x64 (which seems to indicate that it is the bit-ness of the assembly(?) the code runs from that determines the bit-ness of the selected driver).